# BigQuery and GROUP BY clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out how Google BigQuery works in respect to aggregation and grouping. I read the documentation and it says for GROUP BY this:

> The GROUP BY clause allows you to group rows that have the same values
>   for a given field. You can then perform aggregate functions on each of
>   the groups. Grouping occurs after any selection or aggregation in the
>   SELECT clause.

So it says that after grouping I can perform aggregate functions (I assume that's functions like COUNT). But than the sentence later it says that grouping occurs after any selection or aggregation in the SELECT clause.

So if I have

```
SELECT f1, COUNT(f2)
  FROM ds.Table
  GROUP BY f1;
```

Which happens first, grouping or counting?

Comment: Trying to understand the goal of the question: What would be different if it was one or the other?

Comment: @fh well the point is to understand how big query works... I actually have no idea how it can work if it does aggregation before group by.. but that's what it says in the documentation. So I was hoping someone can explain that. And because you're on Google Developer Relations team you seem like a perfect person for this question :)

Comment: I see what you mean. While we review the documentation internally, be assured that BigQuery does the only sane thing it could in this case. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I'm not sure if you really want to know how BQ works or just pointing out the strange explanation in docs. In the first case, to my humble knowledge, BQ is Dremel based and you can try this: [link](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/cs//pubs/archive/36632.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You will have the group and then the count. In your case you would get a single line for each f1 and then the count.

However, if you want to do something interesting, you could use window functions in which first you can group by some fields, and then you can execute functions against the resulting rows, which is quite handy.

Take a look at the window functions section of the bigquery online docs for a few examples on this.